# Can Varnish generate ETags?

Tags: caching, varnish, etag

Is there some way to have Varnish generate a ETag for a backend response it recieves and add it to the response? I would prefer to have all ETag logic in Varnish instead of configuring this for all my backend nodes individually.

I'm using Varnish 4.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Etags are not currently implemented in Varnish ([see the wiki](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ETags)).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the etag header and its value in VCL if you wish.

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (!beresp.http.Etag) {
        set beresp.http.Etag = "W/foo";
    }
}
```

The main issue here is how to make the Etag reflect the body of the object. You'll have to know how your application works to do this safely. One approach could be to feed the Date response header along with the URL to libvmod-digest, and set the hash output as the Etag.

In Varnish 4.0.0 you have (the wiki is outdated) support for If-Modified-Since/If-None-Match to the backend, so if you choose to do this in VCL remember to filter it in vcl_backend_fetch so you don't confuse your backend.

In general I'd advice against doing this in VCL. Adding it on the backend is usually just enabling a module. The actual change in VCL is simple, but this is one of the tricky parts of HTTP and it is easy to get it wrong.